# Why does this code works with protected, not private?

Tags: ruby

I am confused about private vs protected here. I have read that it is impossible to call private and protected methods on the objects created outside of the class. And that I can use them in public methods. So, why does this code work with protected, not private?

```
class Student
  def initialize(name, grade)
    @name = name
    @grade = grade
  end

  def better_grade_than?(other_student)
    grade > other_student.grade ? true : false
  end

  protected
  def grade
    @grade
  end

end

class Joe < Student
end

class Bob < Student
end

joe = Joe.new('Joe', 88)
bob = Bob.new('Bob', 60)

puts joe.better_grade_than?(bob) # true
puts bob.better_grade_than?(joe) # false
```

If private, it outputs NoMethodError.

Comment: *"If a method has protected visibility, it is callable only where `self` of the context is the same as the method."* in this case when calling `other_student.grade` within `better_grade_than?` the context of `self` is an instance of `Student` so calling `other_student.grade` is permitted in this context.

Comment: Note: `grade > other_student.grade ? true : false` is poor practice. The comparison already yields a boolean value. You could just return `grade > other_student.grade`

Comment: "I have read that it is impossible to call private and protected methods on the objects created outside of the class." – Umm, where did you read this? It makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read that it is impossible to call private and protected methods on the objects created outside of the class.

This is wrong.

## `private`

`private` means "can only be invoked by a message send with an implicit receiver of `self` or with an explicit receiver that is the literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`".

In other words, a `private` method `qux` can only be invoked by message send like this:

```ruby
qux      # implicit receiver
```

or like this:

```ruby
self.qux # `self` keyword as the explicit receiver
```

It can *not* be called with *any other receiver*. Not even with `self` as the receiver, *unless* it is the actual, literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`:

```ruby
this = self
self.qux
# private method `qux' called (NoMethodError)
#
#     this.qux
#         ^^^^
```

You can try it yourself:

```ruby
class C
  def foo = qux
  def bar = self.qux

  def baz
    this = self
    this.qux
  end

  private def qux; end
end

o = C.new

o.foo
o.bar
o.baz
```

I am not sure where you read the statement you quoted, but I recommend always reading an official source.

This is what section 13.3.5.3 *Private methods* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) has to say, for example:

> ## 13.3.5.3 Private methods
>
> A private method is a method whose visibility attribute is set to the private visibility.
>
> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation, except for a method invocation of any of the following forms where the *primary-expression* is a *self-expression*.
>
> - *single-method-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-method-assignment*
> - *single-indexing-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-indexing-assignment*

Note that the ISO Ruby Programming Language Specification has not been updated since 2012, so this is a slightly outdated definition. The specification was slightly simplified a couple of years ago. Nowadays, the second paragraph should probably read more like this:

> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation, except for a method invocation where the *primary-expression* is a *self-expression*.

But note that this doesn't make a difference here, since in your code you are not using a *self-expression* as the receiver anyway, so whether a *self-expression* is allowed in a limited number of cases or always is irrelevant.

The [ruby/spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) for [`private`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/private_spec.rb) and for [message sends](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/send_spec.rb) also does not seem to be fully up-to-date, but again, the differences do not matter for your question.

The RDoc for [Modules](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html), specifically, the [subsection on Visibility](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Visibility), however, is fully up-to-date and pretty clear:

> The third visibility is private. A private method may only be called from inside the owner class without a receiver, or with a literal `self` as a receiver. If a private method is called with a receiver other than a literal `self`, a `NoMethodError` will be raised.

## `protected`

`protected` means "can only be invoked by a message sent from a sender which is an instance of the module the method is defined in".

In other words, if you have a `protected` method `m` defined in module `M` like this:

```ruby
module M
  protected def m; end
end
```

Then `m` can only be invoked by a message send where the sender is an instance of `M`:

```ruby
kind_of?(M) #=> true
M === self  #=> true

receiver.m
```

I *think* a succinct way to phrase the test would be something like:

```ruby
kind_of?(receiver.method(:m).owner) # must be `true`
```

Here's what section 13.3.5.4 *Protected methods* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification has to say:

> ## 13.3.5.4 Protected methods
>
> A protected method is a method whose visibility attribute is set to the protected visibility.
>
> A protected method can be invoked if and only if the following condition holds:
>
> - Let *M* be an instance of the class `Module` in which the binding of the method exists.
>   *M* is included in the current self, or *M* is the class of the current self or one of its superclasses.
>
> If *M* is a singleton class, whether the method can be invoked or not may be determined in an implementation-defined way.

And the RDoc:

> The second visibility is `protected`. When calling a protected method the sender must inherit the `Class` or `Module` which defines the method. Otherwise a `NoMethodError` will be raised.
>
> Protected visibility is most frequently used to define `==` and other comparison methods where the author does not wish to expose an object’s state to any caller and would like to restrict it only to inherited classes.

> So, why does this code work with protected, not private?

It doesn't work with `private` because here you are sending a message with an explicit receiver that is not the literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`:

```ruby
grade > other_student.grade ? true : false
#       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

The receiver is `other_student`, but if `grade` is `private`, then it can only be invoked by a message send with an implicit receiver (`grade`) or with an explicit receiver of `self` (`self.grade`).

It *does* work with `protected` because `other_student` is an instance of `Student`.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `protected` methods are accessible to the class that defines it **and** and classes that inherit from it. On the other hand, `private` methods are **only** accessible by the class that defines it.

So in your example `protected` works because Joe and Bob both inherit from Student, so they can use it's protected methods.

Comment: So, private methods are never inherited?

Comment: @iBug, so if class B accesses a2 and a1 created in the parent class, why then grade method should be protected? why code works when the method is protected? I understood from your words that methods in class B can access private/protected methods from A, but it confuses me with the author's answer.

Comment: @doriangrey Sorry, I realize there were some misunderstandings on my side. I've deleted that comment and hope it doesn't confuse you anymore.

Comment: @doriangrey `private` methods are inherited but cannot be called with a receiver at all, not even `self` in the context they are defined. e.g. `class A; def hello; self.hi; end; def hi; 'Hi'; end; private :hi; end` then `A.new.hello #=>  NoMethodError (private method hi'`

Comment: @engineersmnky, your code works btw